# How do you loop through different rows (bootstrap rows) in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am asking myself: How would you loop through different rows using *ngFor?
Lets say an array is given

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4] // arr can have a arbitrary number of elements
```

Now I want to loop trough that array and display the values. I want two elements to be in a row (using bootstrap 4.0). My approach:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6" *ngFor="let el of arr"> {{el}} </div>
</div>
```

Now I would have this html-code

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6"> 1 </div>
    <div class="col-6"> 2 </div>
    <div class="col-6"> 3 </div>
    <div class="col-6"> 4 </div>
</div>
```

but I want it this way:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6"> 1 </div>
    <div class="col-6"> 2 </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6"> 3 </div>
    <div class="col-6"> 4 </div>
</div>
```

because this would be correct regarding the elements in a row.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Option 1

The quickest option would be to use the [`slice`](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe) pipe. But it might not be suitable for large data sets.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6" *ngFor="let el of arr | slice:0:2"> {{el}} </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6" *ngFor="let el of arr | slice:2:4"> {{el}} </div>
</div>
```

#### Option 2

Split the array into chunks of arrays and loop through them.

Controller

```js
export class AppComponent  {
  arr = [1,2,3,4];
  finalArr = [];    // <-- [[1,2], [3,4]]

  constructor(private http: HttpClient){
    for (let i = 0, j = this.arr.length; i < j; i += 2) {
      this.finalArr.push(this.arr.slice(i, i + 2));
    }
  }
}
```

Template

```html
<div class="row" *ngFor="let arr of finalArr">
  <div class="col-6" *ngFor="let el of arr"> {{el}} </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve it without second loop provided col-6 is fixed.

```
<div>
  <ng-container  *ngFor="let el of arr; index as i">
    <div class="row" *ngIf="i%2 === 0">
            <div class="col-6" > {{arr[i]}} </div>
            <div class="col-6" > {{arr[i+1]}} </div>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

This will do as you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

From the pattern it looks like a outer and a inner loop will solve the problem. 
outer loop will control the "row" - div
inner loop will control the "col-6" - div
Kindly give it a try.

Comment: So do I have to calculate how many row I would need if I had x elements? For example 12 elements means 6 rows. Does it have to be so complicated?